# Way to understand this code. How is it working?

Tags: javascript, scoping, hoisting

I was exploring scopes in javascript and came to know this problem. I don't understand how this problem is working.

```js
function checkType() {
  return foo;
  foo = 10;

  function foo() {};
  var foo = 11;
};

console.log(typeof checkType())
```

My question is this how does javascript compiler decide to return function not variable. Any reference or explanation are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the compiler will compile the above code..

```
function checkType() {
  var foo = function() {}; /* function will be hoisted to the top, 
                              and will be assigned to the variable as 
                              the name is the same for the two.. */
  return foo;

  // Code will never reach here as you are returning before this
  foo = 10;
  foo = 11;
};

console.log(typeof checkType());
```

Functions which are defined using `function()` syntax will be hoisted, in this case, the nested function will be hoisted insde the `checkType()` and hence, the `checkType()` returns the function instead of the integer.

> Note: Because the function was defined using `function(){}` syntax, it
>   was hoisted to the parent function scope, else, if the function was
>   defined using `var foo = function() {}` then the hoisting would not
>   have worked in the same way, your function would've returned `undefined` instead.

**More reference on Scoping & Hoisting**

- http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting/

Answer (score 1):

First all the function declarations are hoisted in a scope. So first of all the code moves the variable `foo` to the top of the scope and initialize its value to function.

The second declaration of variable is not hoisted because the function declaration is already hoisted. So the code is same as

```
function checkType() {
  var foo = function(){}
  return foo;
  foo = 10;

  foo = 11; 
};
```

Comment: @Nitin: The [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/).

Answer (score 0):

When we run a code there are two phase of it first is `creation phase` in this phase the syntax parser will read the code and hoist the function and variables, and second phase is `execution phase` in which the values are assigned to hoisted variables,

> ***A point to note*** here is function are stored in memory during creation phase as it is where as the variables are hoisted but values
>   are not initialized ( which will be assigned during execution phase )

Compiler will treat your code like this after hoisting

```js
function checkType() {
  var foo = function() {}; //hoisted function
  return foo;
  foo = 10;
  foo = 11;
};

console.log(typeof checkType(), '\nRturned value from function  --->', checkType())
```

If you define your function as variable than it will be hoisted only but will not be initialized with value, you can see the below example

```js
function checkType() {
  return foo;
  foo = 10;

  var foo = function foo() {};
  var foo = 11;
};

console.log(typeof checkType(), '\nRturned value from function  --->', checkType())
```